# How can I implement swipe up navigation with Stacks in react-native similar to TikTok?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

In `App.tsx`, I have:

```
export default function App() {

  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='feed' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, gestureDirection: 'vertical' }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="feed" component={IvoryFeedScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen} />

      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

How can I have these stacks swipe-up-able like in TikTok?

Comment: I would use `react-native-swiper` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [react-native-pager-view](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view) to implement scroll same like tiktok

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';

const MyPager = () => {
  return (
    <PagerView style={styles.pagerView} initialPage={0}>
      <View key="1" style={styles.page}>
        <Text>First page</Text>
      </View>
      <View key="2" style={styles.page}>
        <Text>Second page</Text>
      </View>
    </PagerView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pagerView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  page: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: How would this work within the Navigation stack? When you swipe, I want to go to a new route

Comment: @Shamoon TikTok is also using pager view, not stack navigation. can you tell me actual use case may be i can help you?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ScrollView for swiper

**try This Example**

```
const abc = [1, 2, 4];
 <FlatList
          horizontal={true}
          data={abc}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
          bounces={false}
          windowSize={1}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          snapToAlignment={'end'}
          snapToInterval={SCREEN_WIDTH}
          decelerationRate={'fast'}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
                  backgroundColor: index === 1 ? 'red' : 'yellow',
                }}></View>
            );
          }}
        />
```

Comment: This could be a valid answer if you provide some more details, such as explanation, code snippets and some documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `snapToInterval` in Flatlist

like

```
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-player'
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

<FlatList
 data={videosList}
 snapToInterval={height/2}
 decelerationRate="fast"
 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 renderItem={({item}) => (
   <VideoPlayer
    video={{ uri: item.source }}
    videoWidth={witdh}
    videoHeight={height}
    thumbnail={{ uri: item.thumbnail }}
/>
)}
 keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}/>
```

where

```
const videosList=[
  {id: '1', source: 'some URL', thumbnail:'some url'},
  {id: '2', source: 'some URL', thumbnail:'some url'},
]
```